# Is it correct to use reflection to call a method in Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, architecture

I have scenario where in the database has method names to be invoked at runtime in some sequence. Do you think Reflection is the best option here.

DB table holds the logic of the methods to be invoked at certain point. As there would be multiple classes with different methods. Based on query I will get the Class name and method name that's to be invoked.

I am little concerned to use reflection in web application at front end / .Net code behind.

Is it better to move these invocation to some background service/ WCF service?

I am looking out for different options that are available.

Comment: Can you provide more details? (an example with 3-4 methods) It is not fully clear what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Think he means that in the database there are method names stored as strings...

Comment: How else would you do this without reflection?

Comment: The front end usually can not use reflection, as no C#code runs there. All the front end can do is use Javascript and perform postbacks. The C# code always runs on the server.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar by front end I mean .Net code behind.

Answer (score 2):

If the intention for having reflection is to keep your application layer flexible for dynamic method invocation, then it makes sense.

*Note that not all non-functional requirements can be met & some architectural principles contradict each other. In this case, **performance & flexibility** are two such extremes and more flexibility will have impact on performance.*

Coming back to your scenario, **recommendation** is be certain on why reflection is required and if it is absolute must (not making it unnecessarily complex), you need to think about other strategies like **caching reflection invocations**, **caching response,** etc.  to make sure performance impact is minimized.

Answer (score 1):

sent from phone!

1. in case it is a closed set of operations, you better use enumeration and switch-case.
2. avoid reflection on anything that has any proximity to user input to avoid injection attacks of some sort
3. if you can, avoid reflections altogether... if you cant:

   3.1. check the data base values.

   3.2. consider running methods in a sandbox and only get sanitized results.

P.S.  mostly when getting to think about complicated solutions, there is a way simpler solution around the corner. so you might want to review the problem that led you thinking about this solution.